# Calculate means beyond a given date R

Tags: r

I have a large dataframe (Merged) of several thousand lines and 20 columns. Each line is a record of a site visit. There are 400 sites in the dataframe and each has multiple lines for visits on different months. . Example:

| Site | Date | Method | Result | ChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2200 | 01/07/2021 | 24 | 0.22 | 01/07/2021 |
| 2201 | 03/07/2021 | 21 | 0.01 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2203 | 03/07/2021 | 21 | 0.02 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2200 | 01/08/2021 | 21 | 0.05 | 01/07/2021 |
| 2201 | 03/08/2021 | 21 | 0.01 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2203 | 03/08/2021 | 21 | 0.02 | 01/01/2021 |
| 2200 | 01/09/2021 | 21 | 0.05 | 01/07/2021 |

And so on for all 400 sites over two years.

I need to calculate the mean result for each site, which I can do:

```
OPmean <- aggregate(Merged$Result, list(Merged$Site), FUN=mean, na.rm = TRUE
```

But I only want to take the means **after** the change date. So on site 2200 I would want to take the mean on these lines only:

| Site | Date | Method | Result | ChangeDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2200 | 01/08/2021 | 21 | 0.05 | 01/07/2021 |
| 2200 | 01/09/2021 | 21 | 0.05 | 01/07/2021 |

Leaving the first line for 2200 off because the date occurs on (or before) the change date.

For an output I would want a new dataframe something like this:

| Site | Mean Result |
| --- | --- |
| 2200 | 0.05 |
| 2201 | 0.01 |
| 2203 | 0.02 |

Comment: Would something like`library(dplyr)` `Merged %>% group_by(Site) %>% filter(Date > ChangeDate) %>% summarize(mr = mean(Result)` work?

Comment: @Michael looks pretty good! I've got a few NA values popped in though that I will need to investigate. Thanks!

Comment: Definitely worth investigating. If you have `NA` in your data you may get `NA`'s back out. To ignore these, you can use `mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2974951 gives a great base R answer. A tidyverse approach might be

```
library(dplyr) 
Merged %>% 
     group_by(Site) %>% 
     filter(Date > ChangeDate) %>% 
     summarize(mr = mean(Result) # or optionally, mean(Result, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Small change to your code

```
aggregate(
  Result~Site,
  data=df[df$Date>df$ChangeDate,],
  FUN=mean
)

  Site Result
1 2200   0.05
2 2201   0.01
3 2203   0.02
```

Comment: Thank you. This led me to a few incorrect results, I can't unpick it to find out why. The code @Michael below worked a treat.